# Complex sorting for core-data fetch request

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have an `NSEntity` (`Cloth`) with an attribute (`type`) which is filled from a list of predefined `NSString` values i.e. Poncho‎, Jacket, Coat, Gown, Top, Suit, etc.

I want to fetch all the Cloth records such that the records are ordered based on a defined order for `type`. i.e. All the records for Poncho‎ are on top, then Jacket, then Coat, then Gown, then Top, then Suit, etc.

```
Poncho‎ …
Poncho‎ …
Poncho‎ …
Jacket … 
Jacket … 
Coat …
Coat …
Coat …
Gown …  
Gown …  
Top …
Top …
Top …
Top …
Suit …  
Suit …
```

This order is not ascending or descending, rather it's custom. How can I fetch the `Cloth` records such that they are returned in this (defined) order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to implement a custom order is to introduce a new attribute of type `NSNumber` to keep track of the order.

[It seems that there is more text after the category string (Poncho, etc), so that you actually have many unique strings that all have to follow a custom order, only that they are grouped by first word.]

If you really want to separate this logic from the rest of the data, you can create a new entity `ClothType` with attributes `name` and `sortOrder` and have a relationship with your `Cloth` entity.

Another scheme is to multiply the sort attribute with, say, 10000 for every "primary" category and add 1 for each subsequent one of the same category.

Answer (score 8):

A Core Data fetch request can only sort on attributes stored in the SQLite database (see [Fetching Managed Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW3) and [Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW11) in the "Core Data Programming Guide".)

You have the following options:

- Fetch all objects and sort them afterwards with a custom sort descriptor. But this will not help if you are using a fetched results controller for a table view.
- Store an additional integer attribute `order` in the `Cloth` entity and use that as sort key. This is perhaps  the easiest one to implement, but you have some redundancy of course.
- Instead of storing the type as string attribute, you could define another entity `Type` which has properties `name` and `order`, and a relationship `type` from `Cloth` to `Type`. In this case you could sort on the key path `type.order`.

Comment: This is really frustrating as SQLite does support expressions for sorting: http://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#ordering-term .  This is a classic anti-pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_inversion

Comment: Core Data not exposing sort functionality could definitely be added to that page...