# is there a way to sort an array by category on ios

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I create a custom sort order on my app?
Suppose that I have a company and my workers are divided by positions inside the factory and I wanna see the performance of my workers on a specific position. I could, on core Data, predicate a result for that but I wanna, at the same time, see more than one positions, like constructor, driver, engineer, etc.
How can I order the fetch request so that the result it should be all of constructors first, the all the drivers and at the end of all of the engineers?

Thanks in advance and I hope that I explained what I want.

Comment: Have you read anything about sort descriptors?

Comment: I read about it on a website and the by the example that they gave, I thought that it wasn't possible. It is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an NSSortDescriptor for the position when you do your fetch from CoreData.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

That will go by the positions alphabetically... if you don't want it done alphabetically then you could implement a new attribute as a NSNumber to keep track of the sort order you want and fetch based upon that. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13044830/1457357) seems to talk a bit about that example.

However, if the order is going to be different at times, you might be better off just holding a NSMutableArray for your total list, and performing the individual fetches for each position, each time adding the results to the end of that same array...

Comment: Thanks! I really don't wanna sort it alphabetically but the nsnumber as a attribute it is the better solution!